# Make langchain to only generate Bigquery query

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-bigquery, langchain

I am developing a langchain bot for BigQuery, using SQLDatabaseChain. However, I've noticed that sometimes the langchain generates queries with different syntax that is not supported in BigQuery. This can result in wasted OpenAI API credits. I have tried using the following custom prompt template:

```
PROMPT = "You need to generate only BigQuery query to retrieve the desired information from the sales dataset. Ensure that the query follows BigQuery syntax and includes the necessary clauses and functions for accurate results."
```

Although there was a slight improvement, the issue still persists. I'm wondering if there is any way to generate only BigQuery queries without encountering unsupported syntax.